# Visual Studio 2017/2019 do not fully open all files of a project folder

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a **GUI folder** contains some files like this ***(focus on the files that I circled in red)***:
[image]

and when I opened the project which contained this folder with file ***.sln**, Visual Studio only displays a few files of this folder on **Solution Explorer**, you can see that VS don't display the files which I circled in red in the image above:
[image]

Anyone can help me, please. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: If its under source control, you need to add them in manually from vs

Comment: Oh my god, It worked, thank you so much bro!!!. I love you <3

Comment: If you see .csproj  file,open it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its under source control, you will have to manually include them in the `SC` from withtin Visual Studio.

More info - [MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/configuring-team-foundation-server-for-web-deployment/adding-content-to-source-control)